# Get the return type based on the parameter

Tags: typescript

I am not sure how to do this, but how do you pass a `typeof XXX` to a method parameter and say that the return type is an instance of that method?

So, I have this method:

```
public getComponent<T>(component: typeof Behavior): Parameters<(c: T) => T> {}
```

I am then using it like this:

```
class Main { 
  getComponent() {
    // Finds an instance and returns it
  } 
}

class Behavior {}
class Item extends Behavior {}


let result = (new Main()).getComponent(Item)
```

TypeScript then says that `result` is an instance of `Behavior` instead of an instance of `Item`. What is the proper way to have the result be an instance of `Item`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```js
getComponent<T extends Behavior>(component: new(...args: any[]) => T): T {}
```

Comment: `getComponent` finds an instance of the type that is passed in from an array and returns the instance.

Comment: Yeah pretty much, however, `Argument of type 'typeof Item' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new () => Item'.` on this line: (new Main()).getComponent(Item)

Comment: seems to work here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-kznhrz

Comment: After some testing, I figured out why that is happening. My class `Behavior` has a constructor in it: `public constructor(val: any){}` That is causing the error.

Comment: I've updated the answer to allow for any form of constructor